# Next.js - ERROR Build directory is not writeable on Google Cloud Build

Tags: next.js, google-cloud-build

I was trying to automate the deployment process of my Next.JS application to App Engine using Cloud Build but at the `build` phase it keeps on failing with:

```
Error: > Build directory is not writeable. https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/build-dir-not-writeable
```

I cant seem to figure out what to fix for this.

My current build file is and it keeps failing on step 2:

```
steps:
  # install dependencies
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
  # build the container image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'build']
  # deploy to app engine
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
  env:
  - 'PORT=8080'
  - 'NODE_ENV=production'
timeout: "1600s"
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs12

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  script: auto

env_variables:
  PORT: 8080
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: whats your next.js version ?

Comment: in my app.yaml i've specified it to use v12. i noticed i missed this out so just added it into my post above

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58614922/next-js-error-build-directory-is-not-writeable-on-ec2) is a related issue with next.js on EC2 where they suggested to set permission to your project directory - `sudo chmod 777 -R /your_project_path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can reproduce the same behavior after upgrading to next version 9.3.3.

### Cause

The issue is related to the npm dependency which is managed by google if you use `gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm` seems they are running your build inside of Google Cloud Build on an old node version.

Here you can find the currently supported version
https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/cloud-builders/GLOBAL/npm?gcrImageListsize=30

As you can see Googles latest node version is 10.10. The newest next.js version requires at least node 10.13

### Solution

Change `gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm` to

```
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
```

in order to use the official docker npm package which runs on node12.
After those changes your build will be successful again.

## Sidenote

Switching to the official npm will increase the build duration (at least in my case). It takes around 2 minutes longer then the gcr npm.

Comment: awesome thanks! that solved it. I would rather take the 2 min delay then have to manually do the deployments which i was stuck with haha