# How to mount NextJS cache in Docker

Tags: docker, caching, next.js, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

Does anyone know a way to mount a Next cache in Docker?

I thought this would be relatively simple. I found buildkit had a cache mount feature and tried to add it to my Dockerfile.

```
COPY --chown=node:node . /code


RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/code/.next/cache npm run build
```

However I found that I couldn't write to the cache as node.

```
Type error: Could not write file '/code/.next/cache/.tsbuildinfo': EACCES: permission denied, open '/code/.next/cache/.tsbuildinfo'.
```

Apparently you need root permissions for using the buildkit cache mount. This is an issue because I cannot build Next as root.

My workaround was to make a cache somewhere else, and then copy the files to and from the `.next/cache`. For some reason the cp command does not work in docker(as node, you get a permission error and as root you get no error, but it still doesn't work.) I eventually came up with this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.3
FROM node:16.15-alpine3.15 AS nextcache
#create cache and mount it
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nxt,target=/tmp/cache \
    mkdir -p /tmp/cache && chown node:node /tmp/cache

FROM node:16.15-alpine3.15 as builder
USER node

#many lines later

# Build next
COPY --chown=node:node . /code
#copy mounted cache into actual cache
COPY --chown=node:node --from=nextcache /tmp/cache /code/.next/cache

RUN npm run build


FROM builder as nextcachemount
USER root

#update mounted cache
RUN mkdir -p tmp/cache

COPY --from=builder /code/.next/cache /tmp/cache

RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nxt,target=/tmp/cache \
    cp -R /code/.next/cache /tmp
```

I managed to store something inside the mounted cache, but I have not noticed any performance boosts.(I am trying to implement this mounted cache for Next in order to save time every build. Right now, the build next step takes ~160 seconds, and I'm hoping to bring that down a bit.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the node user in a node official image, which happens to have uid=1000 and the same gid, I think you should specify that when mounting the cache so that you have permission to write on it:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/code/.next/cache,uid=1000,gid=1000 npm run build
```

Comment: Now its telling me a build error occured. "Error: > Build directory is not writeable." in at /code/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:286:23.

Comment: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58614922/next-js-error-build-directory-is-not-writeable-on-ec2) that had a similar error, but unfortunately adding `RUN sudo chmod 777 -R /code` before the build didn't change the outcome.